# ngClick with parameter does not pass the parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, angularjs-ng-repeat, parameter-passing

I got a treelike table with two ng-repeats.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat-start="am in anArray">
<td><button ng-click="TheFunction(am)"></button></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-start="em in anotherArray">
<td><button ng-click="TheFunction2(em)"></button></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

With some function to show/hide the "correct" line the result on screen is a tree with each row having a button to call a function defined in the scope.
In the controller I defined the function:

```
$scope.TheFunction=function(am){
alert(am); //and other things to do with the am object
}
$scope.TheFunction2=function(em){
alert(em); //and other things to do with the am object
}
```

If I run the page, the treelike construct is working as expected, all buttons are shown. If I click on a button the correct function is called. But, when I check the passed parameter, it is undefined.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: why not use ng-repeat and get rid of the ng-repeat-end rows?

Comment: I use the start/end syntax to make it easier to read (at least for me), it shouldnt affect the parameter passing I think?

Comment: Can't reproduce problem with [this DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3wtdsnL/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code.. It worked with both `ng-repeat` and `ng-repeat-start`. I used `ng-repeat` since it is cleaner..

See if this works for you:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('main', main)

function main($scope){
  $scope.anArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
  $scope.anotherArray = ["dog", "cat", "mouse"];
  $scope.TheFunction=function(am){
    alert(am); //and other things to do with the am object
  }
  $scope.TheFunction2=function(em){
   alert(em); //and other things to do with the am object
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-view ng-controller="main">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="am in anArray">
  <td><button ng-click="TheFunction(am)">{{am}}</button></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="em in anotherArray">
  <td><button ng-click="TheFunction2(em)">{{em}}</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly did you change except the app and controller definition I didnt copy into 'my' code?

Comment: used `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`.. You can see that this simple example works in the snippet.. If you still can't get it to work please also post the part of your controller that includes the arrays..

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand why your code is working and mine not.
Is there a known bug when using the start-end-syntax?

Comment: It's hard to tell just by the information you've provided.. Please provide more info.. such as more of your code and we can have a better look

Comment: I will look through my code again with a mate tommorrow, if we cant figure out what is causing the problem I will post more code here. Thanks